# Wherebetween closure laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have in Product model variable `appends` with:

```
protected $appends = ['finalPrice'];

public function getFinalPriceAttribute()
{
    if ($this->discount_type == 1) {
        return intval($this->price -= $this->discount);
    } elseif ($this->discount_type == 0) {
        return intval($this->price * (1 - $this->discount / 100));
    }

    return $this->price;
}
```

When I want use this attribute on wherebetween I get error: `undifined column finalPrice`:

```
 $_products = Product::active()
        ->whereBetween('finalPrice', [$whereSum['min'], $whereSum['max']])
        ->orderBy($orderColumn, $orderBy);
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Because this custom attribute is not part of the table, it is not selectable by a query. Eloquent queries translate to SQL queries. You could perform the filtering on a Collection, however for bigger datasets this might be slow.

Comment: @Thomas what I can do in this cause?

Answer (score 0):

Your Eloquent is:

```
$_products = Product::active()
        ->select('id',DB::raw("(CASE WHEN discount_type = 1 THEN price discount WHEN discount_type = 0 THEN price * (1 - / 100) END) as new_price)"))
        ->orderBy($orderColumn, $orderBy);
```